# D8 - I need to use many services on my block, is this code right?

Tags: drupal-8

Developing a Drupal 8 example site, I have declared block in a module, and I want to do a few things with this block, like check the route and show this block only on nodes, also check if the user has permissions to see this block, and the content of the block is a form which I had defined in another place of the module.

I don't want to get the classes/services that I need in a static way, I want to use dependency injection to get those classes because it is technically better to decouple code and allow better testing.

Now "create" method and the "constructor" method on the block are like so:

```
<?php    
public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('current_user'),
      $container->get('form_builder'),
      $container->get('current_route_match'),
      $container->get('access_check.permission')
    );
}


  public function __construct(
    array $configuration, $plugin_id,
    $plugin_definition,
    AccountProxyInterface $user,
    FormBuilderInterface $formBuilder,
    ResettableStackedRouteMatchInterface $route,
    AccessInterface $access
    ) {

     parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
     $this->user = $user;
     $this->formBuilder = $formBuilder;
     $this->route = $route;
     $this->access = $access;
  }
```

Is this the correct way to do this? Maybe I'm doing too much in the block file? Should I create a service to move the logic to another place? Probably I would need more things, which means using more services, and my "create" and "constructor" methods are growing in parameters. Is this the correct way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have to inject many services in one class, be it a controller or a block, it usually tells that the class is not well designed because you are (probably) trying lots of things in just one class.

However, I've seen many controllers which inject multiple services in their constructors, so it doesn't seem an unusual practice anyway. "Every rule has an exception".

In the end, I think it is a matter of balance, build a class that is responsible for doing one logical thing, and its dependencies in the same way.